# received new Sales job offer - background check before turn in notice?

Tags: job-offer, resignation, background-check

ok,
I received a job offer and accepted it for a software sales position.  They have start date set and the HR person said it takes about 5-7 working days for the background check.  I'm nervous to not turn in my notice at my current employer until it the background check is clear - 
I don't have any criminal records but I did file bankruptcy 5 years ago,  should I be worried about not passing for a sales position?

Answer (score 1):

Most background checks are interested in criminal behavior and verifying your employment history. Yes, they can do a credit check.  But the simple fact is that they don't have a reason to unless you're getting a security clearance or working in the financial industry.  Yes, there could be an exception, but that's been my experience.  They really don't care about your credit in most cases.

Having said that, you don't have a new job yet until you've passed the background check. And the rule is that you shouldn't quit a job for the hope of another one when you don't actually have it.

In the US, "notice" is a courtesy, nothing more.  If you feel you need to wait so you don't find yourself without a job, do that.

Comment: thanks for the insight,  I feel confident in passing the check but I'm not going to give notice here until I get confirmation on being cleared from new employer,  thx

Comment: I think that's smart.  Background checks aside, I've seen plenty of jobs that were confirmed suddenly fall apart at the last minute for many reasons. At least you'll be safer this way in case something happens.

Comment: In my experience, companies usually don't bother to contact you just to tell you that you passed the background check. If you don't hear from them within 4-5 days, you should probably call them and ask.

Comment: That's actually a good point @AffableAmbler. I'd set a deadline and then call and ask them, "wanted to check on things and make sure we're still on track for ____ and see if there's any other information they need."